# How to create Django Models based on DTD file/XML

Tags: xml, django, dtd

I am new to this xml and dtd files. I need your help on how to create my models in order to upload an xml file in it. 
The files i have to work with can be found under these 2 links:

***XML fomat:***
https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/europeaid/fsd/fsf/public/files/dtdFullSanctionsList/content?token=dG9rZW4tMjAxNw

***DTD format:***
https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/europeaid/fsd/fsf/public/files/dtdFullSanctionsListSchema/content?token=dG9rZW4tMjAxNw

The DTD file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT WHOLE (ENTITY+)>
<!ATTLIST WHOLE
    Date CDATA #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT ENTITY (NAME+, ADDRESS*, BIRTH*, PASSPORT*, CITIZEN*)>
<!ATTLIST ENTITY
    Id CDATA #REQUIRED
    Type (E | P) #REQUIRED
    legal_basis CDATA #IMPLIED
    reg_date CDATA #IMPLIED
    pdf_link CDATA #IMPLIED
    programme CDATA #IMPLIED
    remark CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT NAME (LASTNAME?, FIRSTNAME?, MIDDLENAME?, WHOLENAME?, GENDER?, TITLE?, FUNCTION?, LANGUAGE?)>
<!ATTLIST NAME
    Id CDATA #REQUIRED
    Entity_id CDATA #REQUIRED
    legal_basis CDATA #IMPLIED
    reg_date CDATA #IMPLIED
    pdf_link CDATA #IMPLIED
    programme CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT LASTNAME (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT FIRSTNAME (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT MIDDLENAME (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT WHOLENAME (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT GENDER (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT TITLE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT FUNCTION (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT LANGUAGE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ADDRESS (NUMBER?, STREET?, ZIPCODE?, CITY?, COUNTRY?, OTHER?)>
<!ATTLIST ADDRESS
    Id CDATA #REQUIRED
    Entity_id CDATA #REQUIRED
    legal_basis CDATA #IMPLIED
    reg_date CDATA #IMPLIED
    pdf_link CDATA #IMPLIED
    programme CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT NUMBER (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT STREET (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ZIPCODE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT CITY (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT COUNTRY (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT OTHER (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT BIRTH (DATE?, PLACE?, COUNTRY?)>
<!ATTLIST BIRTH
    Id CDATA #REQUIRED
    Entity_id CDATA #REQUIRED
    legal_basis CDATA #IMPLIED
    reg_date CDATA #IMPLIED
    pdf_link CDATA #IMPLIED
    programme CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT DATE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT PLACE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT PASSPORT (NUMBER?, COUNTRY?)>
<!ATTLIST PASSPORT
    Id CDATA #REQUIRED
    Entity_id CDATA #REQUIRED
    legal_basis CDATA #IMPLIED
    reg_date CDATA #IMPLIED
    pdf_link CDATA #IMPLIED
    programme CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT CITIZEN (COUNTRY?)>
<!ATTLIST CITIZEN
    Id CDATA #REQUIRED
    Entity_id CDATA #REQUIRED
    legal_basis CDATA #IMPLIED
    reg_date CDATA #IMPLIED
    pdf_link CDATA #IMPLIED
    programme CDATA #IMPLIED
>
```

So if someone could help me with my model creation in order to upload this xml file by using the DTD, I would owe you a lot!

Thank you!

Comment: So you want to parse all the data and create corresponding models and load data from it?

Answer (score 2):

So I don't know any automated way of creating the model from a XML. You probably have to do this by hand. In general lines:

- You need to create the models (models.py) and that really depends on how you understand your data. Based on the XML you've sent it should look like this:

  ```
  class Entity(models.Model):
     id = models.IntegerField()
     type = models.CharField(max_length = 1)
     legal_basis = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
     etc...
  ```

Identation points to the need of a foreign key, but lastname, firstname look unique for each name, so next class:

```
class Name(models.Model):
   id = models.IntegerField()
   entity_id = models.ForeignKey('Entity')
   legal_basis = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
   etc...
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
   whole_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
   etc...
```

Birth and passport also need classes with foreign key to entity. Note that those classes can be greatly improved by choosing max_length correctly, and assgning uniqueness on your ids, etc.

- Next you need a script that open the xml and writes on the model you've just created. It can be located on the root of your django app (not project). This should start like this (use [elementTree library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)):

  ```
  import os
  import sys
  import django 

  #this loads django so you can deal with models
  sys.path.append("/path/to/project/")
  os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "your_project.settings"
  django.setup() 

  #import your models.py
  from yourapp.models import *

  #import XML parser and your file
  import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
  tree = ET.parse('your_file.xml')
  root = tree.getroot()
  ```
- Next you need some handcrafting. Loop over your XML (which is inside your root variable) and use the elementtree API to grab stuff. Then use Django ORM to write to your model.

This is just ignoring the DTD file.  You basically need to reproduce its rules in django models language.

Tell me if you need more details.

Hope it helps.